# RSS update via sms

Tags: php, mobile

i was thinking about designing a service that can provide my subscribers feed updates whenever a new content gets added via sms. Can anybody please tell how to go about the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for kind of free service, try the txtWeb.com

They allow you to create SMS applications and integrate it with their SMS platform for free.

So, what you have to do is, do the serverside coding in some language like PHP. Then integrate it with the txtWeb service. And your customers or friends could easily access it via SMS.
BTW, I have created 2 applications using this service. One is for my friends to check the exam result(of my college) and the other one for getting the latest headlines of a local newspaper. I haven't maintained it for some months now. Might probably need an update. :)

Otherwise, if you are looking for pro way, then you have to get a SMS package(maybe bulk service) and make use of the API provided by the service provider to create the application. This will cost you some money. And I heard that there are some new rules in India : http://connectbysms.com/new-trai-rules-in-india/
This would cost you large, if someone had reported about your service..!

Hope it will help you. :)