# RSS alert via sms

Tags: php, mobile, rss, sms

I was searching for a service that can provide RSS updates via sms also any such API that I may integrate so that my subscribers can get updates for their subscribed RSS feeds via SMS. Perhaps an open source implementation will be more favorable.

Comment: You are looking for SMS gateway.

Comment: you asked about it yesterday ! : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849220/rss-update-via-sms

Comment: I have tried Googling it and found many results showing some free services that does the same thing : https://www.google.com/search?q=rss+via+sms

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience Akhilesh but i wasn't able to use txtweb for the purpose i wanted to use it so had to post again.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the question. There is some PHP and Javascript coding involved plus the use of a cloud telephony app called Tropo as well as configuring Windows Task Scheduler with a Visual Basic file (.vbs) to run as a kind of client-side cron-job. ~Eric